# semantic-ui modal - page jumpes to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, semantic-ui

I use a semantic-ui modal box. When the modal pops up the dimmed page in the background jumps to the top. When closed it jumps back to the button that opened it. In the docs the page in the background stays in place. What am I missing out?

Answer (score 2):

found it
I use as a button `<a href="#">`
I now use a simple div and it all stays in place.